# Auto-open NERDTree in vim

Tags: linux, unix, vim, nerdtree

Does someone know how to force .vimrc to auto-open NERDTree each time vim is invoked? The operation system is *nix.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
 au VimEnter *  NERDTree
```

in your vimrc should do it

:he autocmd.txt for background

Answer (score 46):

You can also only open Nerd Tree when there was no file on the command line:

```
function! StartUp()
    if 0 == argc()
        NERDTree
    end
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call StartUp()
```

Taken from a [blog post by Ovid](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2011/04/nerdtree-on-startup.html).

Comment: Very nice tip. Thank you. (I don't know why nobody upvoted that before).

Comment: This _should_ be the accepted solution.  It's a PITA when the tree opens when a file is passed in as a CLI argument, and you have to C-WW over every time.

Answer (score 10):

One liner to open NERDTree when no file argument provided would be

```
autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif
OR
au vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif
```

The above code just checks if no argument is provided then open `NERDTree`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @zoul's answer, I in my case I wanted NERDTree to be open by default if I specify a directory or if I specify nothing, and not be open if I specify a single file, so I ended up with:

```
function! StartUp()
    if !argc() && !exists("s:std_in")
        NERDTree
    end
    if argc() && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in")
        exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0]
        wincmd p
        ene
    end
endfunction

autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * call StartUp()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to have a persistent NERDTree, that remains even when you open new tabs, you'd better use [jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) and add in your `.vimrc` :

```
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1
```

The package is not maintained anymore, but it works and I don't know any equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official answer in NERDTree Document.

https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree#how-do-i-open-nerdtree-automatically-when-vim-starts

```
" Start NERDTree and leave the cursor in it.
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

---

```
" Start NERDTree and put the cursor back in the other window.
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
```

---

```
" Start NERDTree when Vim is started without file arguments.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists('s:std_in') | NERDTree | endif
```

---

```
" Start NERDTree. If a file is specified, move the cursor to its window.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | if argc() > 0 || exists("s:std_in") | wincmd p | endif
```

---

```
" Start NERDTree, unless a file or session is specified, eg. vim -S session_file.vim.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists('s:std_in') && v:this_session == '' | NERDTree | endif
```

---

```
" Start NERDTree when Vim starts with a directory argument.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists('s:std_in') |
    \ execute 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | enew | execute 'cd '.argv()[0] | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In your vim config file (I use nvim, so for me its in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`), 
 Add the line anywhere in the file:
`au VimEnter *  NERDTree`